# Select distinct combinations of values

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table with X values and Y values, both INT. What I want to do is group on the X value with the condition that it contains a distinct combination of Y values. I also want to see the total number of each combination.

I tried using SUM ( POWER (2, Y)), but that generates numbers that are too big as Y can get up to about 300 in some cases.

```
+--------------+--------------+
|            X |            Y |
+--------------+--------------+
|            1 |            1 |
|            1 |            2 |
|            1 |            4 |
|            1 |            6 |
|            2 |            1 |
|            2 |            2 |
|            2 |            4 |
|            2 |            6 |
|            3 |            2 |
|            3 |            3 |
|            3 |            5 |
|            4 |            2 |
|            4 |            3 |
|            4 |            5 |
|            5 |            2 |
|            5 |            3 |
|            5 |            6 |
+--------------+--------------+
```

I want the result to look something like:

```
+--------------+--------------+
|            X |        COUNT |
+--------------+--------------+
|            1 |            2 |
|            3 |            2 |
|            5 |            1 |
+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask]. Hint: some sample data (prefrebly ddl+dml) and desired result would help us to help you.

Comment: i deleted my answer, because i did not understand what you wanted :-) (to be honest, i still dont do)

Comment: Clarified some more. I want to count distinct combinations of Y values belonging to the same X value.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description (but not on your sample data) next query should do:

```
select X, count(distinct Y)
from TBL
group by X
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for trying to help. I realize that it might have been hard to understand what I was trying to do.

Anyway, I ended up solving it with the checksum_agg aggregate function.